# Nested collection root element in JSON - Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to deserealize a JSON in a object using Jackson 1.9 and mixin feature of the jackson library. Generally it works fine for me, but right now I have a JSON which has a nested root element.

I am using the following expression  -

> mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);

My class structure is like

```
class Animal
   List<Horse> getRacingAnimals();
   private String color;

class Horse
   horse properties...
```

And here is the JSON sample -

> {"myanimal":{"color":"black", "racingAnimals":{"horse":["List of horses"]}}}

Now I have used a mixin to map custom properties and root name

```
@JsonRootName("myAnimal")
public abstract class ConfigurationMixin {

@JsonProperty("racingAnimals") abstract List<Horse> getRacingAnimals(); }
```

Now if you look at the JSON above apart from the "myAnimal" root element there is another root element which is called "horse", how should I specify another root element in the mixin or do I need to prepare another mixin for it, if yes that how would that look like.

Currently I have

> mapper.getDeserializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(Animal.class,    ConfigurationMixin.class);

I am not sure about the syntax of the new mixin as the property racingAnimals is parent node of the root elemement "Horse" and I can't use annotations like @JSONRootElement on the actual source code as I don't have access to the source code.

Comment: You mean there is a element as root element and there is another element inside with the same name ??

Comment: Hi @Nanoc, No I mean there is another element inside which is a Json object "horse" which is basically the root of the "list of horses"

Comment: Then just create your model class and let Jackson populate it